# When to use Parent.__init__(self) and not to use it?

Tags: oop, python-2.7, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have this code:

```
class Pere():
    def __init__(self, nom):
        self.nom = nom
    def yeux(self):
        print 'les yeux bleus'

class Mere():
    def __init__(self, nom):
        self.nom = nom
    def taille(self):
       print 'je suis longue!'

class Enfant(Pere, Mere):
    pass
```

And in some tutorials speaking about `inheritance`, they use `ParentClass.__init__(self, *args)` for the child constructor.

Here is the example where it is used:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, nom, age):
        self.name = nom
        self.age = age
    def __str__(self):
        return 'je suis {0}, et j\'ai {1} ans'.format(self.name, self.age)

class Militaire(Person):
    def __init__(self, nom, age, grade):
        Person.__init__(self, nom, age)
        self.grade = grade
    def __str__(self):
        return Person.__str__(self) + ' et je suis un {0}'.format(self.grade)
```

When to use it?

In multiple inheritance, we dont need it (write it twice for example if it exists)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unbound-method call (`Parent.__init__(self, ...)`) does not work well in general **with multiple inheritance** -- just like simply inheriting `__init__` (if delegating to the parent is all you do in the method in your subclass, **don't** -- just omit defining the method in the subclass so it inherits from the superclass).

In your example that's totally moot since both superclasses have identical implementations of `__init__` (in the original Q, now edited to change that), so it doesn't really matter what you do.

More generally, that's what `super` was introduced for -- it works smoothly in Python 3, a bit less in Python 2 (in the latter case, only for new-style classes, normally inheriting from `object` -- but then nobody should be defining old-style classes any more!-), but it still works for multiple inheritance much better than older approaches such as explicitly calling `Parent.__init__` (it only works well if every class in the hierarchy cooperates, though).

See e.g [Understanding Python super() with __init__() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods) for more about `super` and the like.

Comment: I am using `2.7`, so, i have to inherit from `Object` for both parent classes to make `super` work? Edit: added a new example

Comment: @Abdelouahab, yes, with Python 2 you need to subclass `object` (or have a global `__metaclass__=type` at the start of your module).  Please tag your Python Qs as being Python 2 or 3 respectively, if they are specific to only one version.

Comment: modified the example and the tag

Comment: so the job of `Parent.__init__(self, ...)` is to repeat writing `self.arg = arg` ?

Comment: @Abdelouahab, it's to let superclasses do whatever initialization work they do -- `self.arg = arg` is only one special case though pretty common.

Comment: it seems that i have a lot to learn with OOP in python, because it is far from being from the easy world of procedural, espetially with this distinction with `py3`

Comment: @Abdelouahab, just avoid multiple inheritance and it becomes crystal simple -- lots of Pythonistas prefer to avoid MI anyway!

Comment: ah! thank you for the device, because this is like i switched another language when it came to OOP! thank you again